# What is the best inheritance model for given example

Tags: java

The main objective is to avoid duplication of fields with best inheritance model on existing stuff:

I have following class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
 private String fieldA1;
 private String fieldA2

 // getters and setters

}

Class B extends A
{
 private String fieldB1;
 private String fieldB2;

 // getters and setters
}
```

A 'User' class will either extend A or B having its own fields.

Assume existing API's uses above data models. 
Now there is a requirement to add new fields in Class A for new set of API's.
I have certain restriction not to modify existing data models since it exposes or breaks existing API's with these new fields . So new data models need to be created by extending existing ones such that new API's uses them with all existing fields + new fields. I have below solution which may not be the best approach as it adds duplication of fields.

```
 class A
    {
     private String fieldA1;
     private String fieldA2

     // getters and setters
    }

    Class B extends A implements Common
    {
     private String fieldB1;
     private String fieldB2;


    // getters and setters
    }


    Class NewA extends A
    {
     private String fieldNewA;

     // getters and setters
    }

   Class NewB extends NewA implements Common
   {
     private String fieldB1;
     private String fieldB2;

     private String fieldNewB;

    // getters and setters

    }

   Interface Common
   {
    //marker interface
   }
```

Please suggest if there is any better approach.

Thanks...

Comment: Minor note: `private fields` don't get inherited.  Now, I'm assuming you will create getters and setters, but consider making them `protected`.

Comment: yes there are getters and setters. Updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to take a step back and look at what is it that is causing you to keep adding new fields to your existing classes. Maybe you should just have one field which is a collection of property and values. This way any new field will just be another property/value in your collection. You won't have to then worry about adding new fields frequently.

Comment: How does adding a new fields will break liskov substitution principle? In this example the existing behaviour of "A" will still remains the same if its derived class just adds new fields and since the base class's fields/methods remain unchanged.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I will delete my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not great, for example sub-classes cannot access private fields and it is not clear what you intend your subclasses to achieve.

If you wish to inherit state, your example should use either protected or public fields, or show getter and setter methods being inherited. When inheriting state, implementing an interface like Common is redundant. More detail may help clarify your intent.

That aside, yes you can extend your data models as you describe in order to add data types to an existing class. An example of wanting to do this might be wishing to create a Square class from a Triangle class, requiring adding a new point. And also requiring changing behaviour to make use of the new field.

Comment: Sorry for missing getters & setters. I have updated the question. So you meant the solution which i mentioned is correct?

Comment: Yes. There are other ways of achieving it, but this is the way if you wish to use Java's single inheritance, giving you both type compatibility and code reuse. Other languages arguably make it easier in that they allow mixins and multiple inheritance. But that is the subject of a different question and involves other trade offs.